# PostGIS jdbc sql query

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgis

I'm trying to use postgis extension for postgresql database and can't get it to work in a way I would like to.
I'm using postgis 2.1.6 (custome build from source) and postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar
(there's additional project with hibernate configuration, but it's probably irelevant for this case).

I have some test code (mainly from postgis example folder):

```
String dburl="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mapwebcatalog";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, dbuser, dbpass);
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

{
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT raw_data_file_points::geometry from raw_data_file_area");

rs.next();
result = (PGobject) rs.getObject(1);
if (result instanceof PGgeometry) {
    System.out.println("PGgeometry successful!");
} else {
    System.out.println("PGgeometry failed!");
}
}

{
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT raw_data_file_points from raw_data_file_area");
rs.next();
result = (PGobject) rs.getObject(1);
if (result instanceof PGgeometry) {
    System.out.println("PGgeometry successful!");
} else {
    System.out.println("PGgeometry failed!");
}
}
```

When I run, I get "PGgeometry successful!" (for first if) and "PGgeometry failed!" (for second if).
And difference is just in explicit type for column (::geometry).

Is this normal, or there is something wrong with configuration?
If this is normal and how it should be, should hibernate generate sql query with type casting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Och, that was stupid mistake. I have geography column in database. With geometry type everything works fine.
or if change driverconfig.properties and add line:

```
datatype.geography=org.postgis.PGgeometry
```

it will work with geography type as well (or use geometry type in db).